# iOS 9 simulator can't show the whole screen

Tags: ios, xcode7

For some reason, when I run some old projects, the simulator can't load the full screen:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: You didn't add the launch screen or 4" launch images.

Comment: Thanks, should I delete this question?